# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) with 'as.matrix': cannot open the connection

Tags: r, matrix

This is my first question here. For now I'm learning how to use R in R-studio, and when I tried to read the data in a matrix form, the program showed the mistake. I tried this code:

```
ModelName = 'new_file' #I'm writing the file name in the same directory as the .r file is
FileName = paste(ModelName, '.txt', sep = '') #as far as I understand, I'm telling the program that 
the file is in the form of txt

### Read Time series
d = as.matrix(read.table(FileName, header= T))
```

And then the program writes this:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': 
cannot open the connection
```

And I don't understand why it's not working.

The file for analysis is in the txt form, the example of data is below:

```
decy Temp CTD_S OxFix Pro Syn Piceu Naneu
 2011.74221     27.60333     36.20700     27.26667  58638.33333  13107.00000    799.66667    117.66667
 2011.74401     26.97950     36.13400     27.05000  71392.50000  13228.50000   1149.00000    116.50000
 2011.74617     24.99750     35.34450     24.80000 264292.00000  27514.00000   2434.50000    132.50000
 2011.74692     24.78400     35.25800     25.82500 208996.50000  39284.00000   3761.75000    220.75000
```

My r-studio version is 4.2.0.

I would be very grateful for explanation.

Comment: R is telling you that it cannot find the file. What is the actual filename? With the code you have written, R will look for `new_file.txt` in the current directory. The `paste()` function you have does not tell R that it is a txt file. It appends `.txt` to whatever you have defined as `ModelName` and saves it as `FileName`. If your real ModelName is `file.txt` or similar, you will end up with `file.txt.txt` and R won't find the file because it does not exist.

Comment: @SamR, the actual filename is "results_ts", and it is in the txt format. I just wrote: 'ModelName = 'results_ts'', no ".txt" added. So the file may be found, as far as I understand, so I don't understand why the problem occurs

Comment: @SamR thank you for your answer! I found the reason the problem occured: the file was in a directory where r file was, but when I looked where the import files were taken from on a default basis, I saw that they were taken from another directory, so now the code works. Thanks a lot!